# Unable to install cucumber gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I'm trying to setup ruby/cucumber tool on my windows 7 PC, I've installed Ruby 2.1.5 and devkit and got installed all the gems except Cucumber.

I'm getting the following error while install cucumber gem.Please help me on this.

ERROR:
Following gems were not installed:
cucumber (2.0.0.rc.4): Error installing cucumber:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150308-6692-1kwvlbm.rb extconf.rb checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options. Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Provided configuration options: Building native extensions. This could take a while... --with-opt-dir --without-opt-dir --with-opt-include --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include --with-opt-lib --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib --with-make-prog --without-make-prog --srcdir=. --curdir --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME) --with-gherkin_lexer_ar-dir --without-gherkin_lexer_ar-dir --with-gherkin_lexer_ar-include --without-gherkin_lexer_ar-include=${gherkin_lexer_ar-dir}/include --with-gherkin_lexer_ar-lib --without-gherkin_lexer_ar-lib=${gherkin_lexer_ar-dir}/lib --with-clib --without-clib C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in`try_link0' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in`try_func' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:966:in `block in have_library' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in`block in checking_for' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in`open' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in`open' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in`checking_for' from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:961:in `have_library' from extconf.rb:5:in`' extconf failed, exit code 1 Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2 for inspection. Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/gherkin-2.12.2/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to try using the current HEAD?

You can specify gem 'cucumber', github: 'cucumber/cucumber' in a Gemfile and try bundle installl

Comment: where is this gemfile located? is it in devkit or ruby?

Comment: The Gemfile it's at the root of your project

Comment: I'm just using ruby not rails so gemFile doesnt exist in my project..pls let me know if there is other way around to resolve this issue

Comment: Try this in the terminal:

gem install cucumber

What is the output?